# Stopping timer after a certain time period

Tags: c#, asp.net, timer

I have a timer on a page in ASP.NET.

After a certain period of time elapses, I want to disable the timer.

Thanks!

Comment: accept more answers..

Comment: WHOA.  You put a time on an ASP.NET page?  Why?  Does that even work?  ...and yes, I agree that you need to accept more answers to get people interested in answering your questions...

Comment: It would be interesting to see your use case here. Why would you need timer in ASP.net application?  If you share the scenario, ppl might be able to help giving you a better solution to it.

Answer (score 1):

In the Timer tick event handler, simply stop the timer.